# Application/documentation for managing flow between servers

Tags: documentation-generator

I'm working on application Integration and with the help of one Network guy we are managing the flows between our application and the others.

To Sum up me problem, we have several version of that application with new/deprecated flows, around 10 Business Unit using this application and several environnement (dev, test, prod...)

I'm looking for someting to manage the documentation of thoses flow, have a visual sum up of the flows and what's working or not, enventually generate curls to test thoses flows directly on the servers. It must be free (or with a good test version), I have to be able to easily share it with my colleagues and show them to non technical guys.

I have tried excel but the file gets quite complicated very fast and hard to share.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Saw your Q on Network, followed here to see what gets suggested.  I think it's preferable to keep these Qs in the topics, but since they won;t I wish they would at least link them.